# How to change optparse's default error message in ruby?

Tags: ruby

```
require 'optparse'
params = ARGV.getopts("a:", "AA")
```

`ruby a.rb -a` shows:

```
a.rb:3:in `<main>': missing argument: -a (OptionParser::MissingArgument)
```

`ruby a.rb -b` shows:

```
a.rb:3:in `<main>': invalid option: -b (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
```

I want to show my help message, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use **on_tail** inside the block of OptionParser.new.

But since you're simply trying with ARGV.getopts, a hack to show your own help message would be rescuing exceptions:

```
require 'optparse'

help_msg = <<EOM
This is help message:
Hello buddy, you may do something wrong
...
EOM

begin
  params = ARGV.getopts("a:", "AA")
rescue => e
  puts e.message
  puts '=' * 80
  puts help_msg
end
```

Output:

```
ruby a.rb -a
#=>
missing argument: -a
================================================================================
This is help message:
Hello buddy, you may do something wrong
...

ruby a.rb -b
#=>
invalid option: -b
================================================================================
This is help message:
Hello buddy, you may do something wrong
...
```